# asp.net CompareValidator not running as expected on submit

Tags: asp.net, comparevalidator

I'm trying to get a CompareValidator to work but having a few problems. If the submit button does not run a function it works fine, but the validator does not work if there is a function attached to the button.

Here's the code.

```
Sub myGo(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    response.redirect("http://www.google.co.uk")
End Sub
```

and

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:TextBox id="txt1" runat="server" /> = <asp:TextBox id="txt2" runat="server" /> <asp:Button OnClick="myGo" Text="not working with onclick" runat="server" /> <asp:Button Text="working button" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:CompareValidator EnableClientScript="false" id="compval" Display="dynamic" ControlToValidate="txt1" ControlToCompare="txt2" Type="String" Text="Validation Failed!" runat="server" />
</form>
```

any ideas?

Comment: If you would enableclientscript, the validator would validate before you redirect. Because you redirect in codebehind, you have to Page.Validate and check for Page.IsValid before you want to redirect in Codebehind. it is always recommended to Validate also on serverside because javascript could be deactivated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validator should work fine, but you probably ought to perform the redirect only if the page is valid:

```
Sub myGo(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Page.IsValid Then
        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.co.uk")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ValidationGroup="...."

Comment: that's not the problem... Frédéric has already hit the nail on the head.